# When listening for messages from a device, what is the unit of AbosoluteTime?

Tags: midi, naudio

When listening for MidiEvents in NAudio from a MidiDevice, we get the long "AbsoluteTime" property on each event.  But what unit is this time in and from what starting point is it measured?

Comment: Based on the discussion here (http://naudio.codeplex.com/discussions/237575), I suspect it is going off of the standard MIDI clock, which means there will be 96 of them per quarter note.  I don't know for certain though, I don't use the NAudio library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a MIDI file, each event has a delta in "ticks" since the last event. To make MIDI files easier to work with, NAudio keeps a running total, storing the value in AbsoluteTime. The meaning of this depends on delta ticks per quarter note (which is a property on the MidiFile class), and the tempo (MIDI files ought to include at least one TempoEvent).

When listening for MIDI events from a device, the AbsoluteTime of the MIDI Event created will be 0. However, you can use the TimeStamp property of the MidiInMessageEventArgs which I believe is in milliseconds since MidiInStart was called.